# Docker and react proxying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, proxy

Problem is this:
i would like to get jwt token from backend that runs on node. I am still learning this stuff (coming from php background) but if i understood correctly, in order to use httpOnly cookie, i must use same url for both back and frontend. That is why i am trying to use proxy in my react app.

Backend and frontend are running in different docker containers (they are completely separate repositories and each has its own docker-compose file). Also they are connected via network.

To summarise, things i've done so far

- installed http-proxy-middleware in react app
- configured proxy as follows:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/api/*", { target: "http://nodebackend:33445" })
  );
};
```

inside node server, i have route configured:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");
  const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
  ... various other routes ...
  app.post("/api/login", users.login)
};
```

Docker-compose.yml for backend:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nodeserver:
    image: node:14
    ports: 
      - 33445:8080
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./app/node_modules:/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - mainnet
    container_name: nodebackend
  
     ... other services such as mysql ...

networks:
  mainnet:
    driver: bridge
```

and Docker-compose.yml in frontend part:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:14
    ports: 
      - 3001:3000
    working_dir: /src
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
    networks:
      - mainnet

networks:
  mainnet:
    external: true
```

they seem to be connected in network correctly (when i do docker network inspect i see containers there)
Also postman request towards backend works (i can receive jwt token in response). So that part works properly

Inside react app i have this code:

```js
const submitLogin = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: "test@test.com", password: "test" }),
  };
  fetch("/api/login", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
       ...do something with the data
    });
};
```

I am stuck with this for days now. No matter what i do, i receive:

`Error occured while trying to proxy: localhost:3001/api/login`

Can someone point me in correct direction, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What port is the `nodeserver` container's main process listening on?  If the process is listening on port 8080, you need to use that port number in the `target:` URL too; connections between containers don't use (or need) `ports:`.

Comment: I have configured 33445:8080 in docker-compose for nodeserver. As you suggested, i tried using 8080 as well but no luck.

Comment: Actually after tearing everything down, and rebuilding from scratch, 8080 port seems to be working! Thanks David Maze! You solved me a headache and i learned something new in a process. And also, if anyone has same issue: use container name, so for me it is nodebackend:8080